# App built using Google Drive PHP SDK keeps redirecting to the same page

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php) to create a sample web app which implements the Google Drive PHP SDK.

When I access the URL, the app keeps redirecting to the same page in an infinite loop, so no content is shown actually. Any idea why this is happening? Is it due to some mistake I made in the config file?

The document says how to implement the sample app - called DrEdit - as a Google Chrome application. Can anyone tell me if it is possible to use the SDK for creating non-Google Chrome apps? Also, does anyone have any example implementation of the Google Drive SDK?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide more information and code, we can debug your first issue.

Otherwise:

- Yes, you can write apps for Drive that are not Chrome apps. Chrome Web Store is an optional distribution mechanism for the API. Your apps will work in any browser.
- There are documented PHP snippets for every API method, e.g. https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/get